# Mysql To execute query and remove special characters

Tags: php

I want to remove special characters when a user input into text box,to do this ,i was using mysql_real_escape_string to do above but today,i see not use this in php manual.

Alternatives to this is  MySQLi or PDO_MySQL .What are the advantages of using this.What is built in function to execute query and remove special characters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Go with PDO. It will nicely handle all the escape stuff and you'll be able to support more databases.

Answer (score 0):

For me, i used

- stripslashes
- strip_tags
- preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9._]/','',$formdata);

For handling _GET information, but also I heard that now you should use **filter_input**